# Three.js Problems using Boxgeometry facevertexUV when rotate the box

Tags: three.js

After look at the code I have seen how every planegeometry is created to every box face.

Faces are created to let normals be consistent. So opposite faces has a different UV behaviour. 
The problem I have found: If you make a simple 90 degrers rotation the 'up' UV direction of opposite faces are different, so you have to take this situation into account.

Is there any 'recomputeUV' or similar function ?

Could it be fixed ?

Thanks.

Comment: UV coordinates are invariant to affine transformations.

Comment: @gaitat. Yes, I know, but I think that certain objects like a box would have a method to support pure 90 degrees rotations. I'm talking about simply change x by y values if necessary.